# Is there any difference between PhD and D.Tech?

Tags: phd, titles

Just out of curiosity, I will like to know if there is any difference (if any) in academic environment, between Ph.D issued by most Universities and D.Tech issued by University of Technology.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've encountered the "D.Tech." degree.  So its value might depend on the willingness of ignorant folks like me to go and find out about it --- whereas we already know what a Ph.D. means (or ought to mean).

Answer (score 5):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Technology), the nature of a D.Tech depends on where it is issued, and who by.  In some cases, it is equivalent to a Ph.D., in other cases it is definitely lesser.  It is certainly not a commonly issued or recognized degree, but that does not mean it has less value if it is from a strong institution.

Answer (score 1):

Typically its awarded in only a few British Commonwealth locations. It was awarded in Australia once as a Professional Doctorate (Deakin Uni) - and as such was at 'roughly' the level of a PhD although Professional doctorates are often considered less 'academic'. In South Africa it is/was common amongst the University of Technology sector. They are considered similar to a professional doctorate - in that they are more practice based than a traditional PhD. In the UK itself however it was once common many years ago in the University of London as a Professional doctorate - ie typically done by working people. Nowadays in the UK it is common as either a Higher Doctorate - typically given to PhD's after they have established themselves via a body of public work such as books and publications and therefore is considered higher than a PhD. Otherwise it is commonly given as an honary doctorate to luminaries in fields related to Engineering or Science. BTW I have a BTech(Hons) and an MTech followed by a PhD from the UK. Perhaps when I am older I will submit my body of work for a DTech. All were from schools of electronic engineering, although its probably impossible to do that today. It was once common at universities like Brunel and Cranfield.